# Extracting specific part of each line in file based on prior string

Tags: parsing, awk

I have a file with lines like the one here:

```
intergenic  NONE(dist=NONE),ENSG00000223972(dist=1692)  1   10177   10177   -   C   1   10177   rs367896724 A   AC  100 PASS    AC=2130;AF=0.425319;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=103152;EAS_AF=0.3363;AMR_AF=0.3602;AFR_AF=0.4909;EUR_AF=0.4056;SAS_AF=0.4949;AA=|||unknown(NO_COVERAGE);VT=INDEL
```

What I would like to do is extract parts I require using the start and end chars. So for instance I would like to extract the value of `AFR_AF`. What I know is that this value begins with `AFR_AF` and ends with `;` (the whole thing looks like: `AFR_AF=0.4909;` so I want the `0.4909`.

I would like to extract multiple parts of each line like to if possible. Is this possible using something like awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A portable solution with `awk`:

```
# extract.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="="
    RS=";"
    search["AFR_AF"]=1
    # Add more items as you wish
    search["FOO_BAR"]=1
    search["HELLO_WORLD"]=1
}

$1 in search {
    print $2
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f extract.awk input.file
```

**Explanation:**

Using `;` as the *record separator (`RS`)*, `awk` sees records like this (instead of line by line):

```
foo=bar
hello=world
no equal sign in this record
...
```

Since we set the *field separator (`FS`)* to `=`, we can check whether the first field `$1` contains a certain value and print the value `$2` in that case.

The search itself is been implemented with an associative array. `$1 in search` checks whether `$1` is a key of that array.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. Would you be able to explain it if its not too much trouble?

Comment: sure. gimme a min

Answer (score 1):

grep with `o` and `P` should help:

```
grep -oP 'AFR_AF=\K[^;]*` file
```

or you want to multiple values in one short, for example:

```
grep -oP '(AFR_AF=|VT=)\K[^;]*' file
```

will give

```
0.4909
INDEL
```